# Laravel : Update if exists, If not delete | Relational data

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I am updating/deleting some form data in database :

The relation is : One to Many: `UserService` => UserServiceVaccine

I am trying to update the table data **if the form have that data**, Otherwise **remove if form data have not the data** :

Current code :

```
foreach ($request->dog_vaccine_required as $key => $vaccine) {
    $serviceVaccination = \App\UserServiceVaccination::updateOrCreate([
        'user_service_id' => $id,
        'vaccine_id' => $vaccine
    ],[
        'specie' => 'Dog',
        'user_service_id' => $id,
        'vaccine_id' => $vaccine,
        'duration_6' => $request->dog_duration_6[$key],
        'duration_12' => $request->dog_duration_12[$key],
        'duration_36' => $request->dog_duration_36[$key]
    ]);
}
```

**It gives me offset exception.** if i remove a checkbox.

**What should be done.**

Comment: deleting in a foreach loop may be a bad idea. Collect the ID's to be deleted inside the loop and delete them outside.

Comment: The IDs to be removed are unknown, Means i am adding the records via checkbox(s), If the checkbox[] (Checkbox are array based), The data is dynamic so we need `[array based input name]`, If any of the checkbox is unchecked on the edit page it should be removed once request posts.

Comment: Why you can not check the result ot selected checkboxs . If nothing is checked delete all the records base on column linked between the UserService and UserServiceVaccine , and if user cheked some of them you call update statment .

Answer (score 0):

Do you can try this ?

```
foreach ($request->dog_vaccine_required as $key => $vaccine) {
    $shouldUpdate=isset($request->dog_duration_6[$key])&&
                  isset($request->dog_duration_12[$key])&&
                  isset($request->dog_duration_36[$key]);

    if ($shouldUpdate){
        $serviceVaccination = \App\UserServiceVaccination::updateOrCreate([
            'user_service_id' => $id,
            'vaccine_id' => $vaccine
        ],[
            'specie' => 'Dog',
            'user_service_id' => $id,
            'vaccine_id' => $vaccine,
            'duration_6' => $request->dog_duration_6[$key],
            'duration_12' => $request->dog_duration_12[$key],
            'duration_36' => $request->dog_duration_36[$key]
        ]);
    }else{
        // Delete
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a "many to many" relationship between user_service table and vaccine table.

Based on the docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

```
$serviceVaccinationArray = [];

foreach ($request->dog_vaccine_required as $key => $vaccine) {
    $serviceVaccinationArray[$vaccine] = [
        'vaccine_id' => $vaccine,
        'specie' => 'Dog',
        'duration_6' => $request->dog_duration_6[$key],
        'duration_12' => $request->dog_duration_12[$key],
        'duration_36' => $request->dog_duration_36[$key]
    ]
}

$userService = UserService::find($id);
$userService->vaccine()->sync($serviceVaccinationArray);
```

The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table.

Comment: `Undefined offset: 2`, If i leave a checkbox unchecked, Checkboxes are optional.

Comment: then add condition to check if checkbox is unchecked
```$request->dog_duration_6[$key] ?? null```